# Can I fix the error: "JSON.parse: unexpected character"

Tags: facebook, json, cross-domain

I'm running into this error.  The app seems to work OK but it causes Firebug to stop the scripts.

```
   JSON.parse: unexpected character
   Line 9 (all.js)
```

The line in question looks like this:

```
FB.provide('JSON',{stringify:function(a){if(window.Prototype&&Object.toJSON){return Object.toJSON(a);}else return JSON.stringify(a);},parse:function(a){return JSON.parse(a);},flatten:function(c){var a={};for(var b in c)if(c.hasOwnProperty(b)){var d=c[b];if(null===d||undefined===d){continue;}else if(typeof d=='string'){a[b]=d;}else a[b]=FB.JSON.stringify(d);}return a;}});
```

I believe the exception is thrown by Firefox's built-in JSON parser, in the parse method defined on that line.  The string being passed to parse looks like this:

```
"cb=f49f4551da8c7e&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9292%2Ff3726c758943f5&relation=parent&transport=postmessage&frame=f2b4bb038098548&code=2.AQ...fU&signed_request=_7hf...E3OCJ9&access_token=AAADj6D4s...ZDZD&expires_in=6650"
```

Obviously this is not a valid JSON string, thus the parse error.

The string comes from an event delivered using the xd_proxy.php somehow, the above string is the hash on the URL for that iframe.

I've searched around a bit and didn't see any useful information about this error.

Comment: After reformatting the javascript code in all.js it looks like the code is designed to catch this exception and retry using a querystring-style parser.  So, it seems like this error should be non-fatal and should be caught by the code.  Seems like Firebug is stopping unnecessarily here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that this exception is correctly caught and handled by the javascript code that calls it, but because I had Firebug set to "break on all errors" it stops execution regardless of whether that exception is caught.

So the fix is actually to turn off "break on all errors" in Firebug, it isn't really a problem with the Facebook scripts at all.